# Clone and then route SNMP traps to new destination

Tags: iptables, snmp, route

We have 2 SNMP trap servers 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 which are the SNMP trap servers for close to 500 devices that we monitor.In all these 500 devices,10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 are configured as the trap destination and any traps generated are sent to both these devices.

We have recently started monitoring a new type of device (IBM Guardium) which has the option of specifying only one trap server.This is causing an issue as only one of the trap server now gets the SNMP trap while the other does not.I have tried looking at the option of setting IP tables to fix this but my understanding of them is quite shallow.

So if I specify 10.0.0.1 as the trap server on the Guardium devices,how do I ensure that not only does 10.0.0.1 receive and store that trap but also clones that trap and sends it to 10.0.0.2 with the original source IP address ?

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with just sending to one destination? that's how many systems work - I don't understand the issue

Comment: the snmp traps are further analysed for plotting realtime graphs ..and the second dstination does that so it is important that the second destination also gets a copy of the trap..

Comment: Why not send it to the second destination then rather than the first?

Comment: the first destination has the algorithm to translate the trap to an alert which is then fed to a monitoring screen..the bottom line is that both the destinations need to have a copy of the trap..